# How to make a console menu

Tags: c++, object-oriented, console

**Showable**

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_SHOWABLE_H
#define REGISTRY_SHOWABLE_H

class Showable {
    
public:

    Showable();

    virtual ~Showable();

    virtual void Show() const = 0;

};


#endif //REGISTRY_SHOWABLE_H
```

```
#include "../include/showable.h"

Showable::Showable() {

}

Showable::~Showable() {

}
```

**Runnable**

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_RUNNABLE_H
#define REGISTRY_RUNNABLE_H

class Runnable {

public:

    Runnable();

    virtual ~Runnable();

    virtual void Run() = 0;
};


#endif //REGISTRY_RUNNABLE_H
```

```
#include "../include/runnable.h"

Runnable::Runnable() {

}

Runnable::~Runnable() {

}
```

**MenuItem**

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_MENUITEM_H
#define REGISTRY_MENUITEM_H

#include "runnable.h"
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class MenuItem : Runnable {

public:

    MenuItem(const std::string &text, const std::function<void()> &function);

    MenuItem();

    ~MenuItem() override;

    void SetText(const std::string &text);

    void SetFunction(const std::function<void()> &function);

    std::string GetText() const;

    std::function<void()> GetFunction() const;

    void Run() override;

private:

    std::string text_;
    std::function<void()> function_;
};


#endif //REGISTRY_MENUITEM_H
```

```
#include "../include/menuItem.h"
using namespace std;

MenuItem::MenuItem(const string &text, const std::function<void()> &function) : text_(text), function_(function) {

}

MenuItem::MenuItem() : text_(""), function_(nullptr) {

}


MenuItem::~MenuItem() {

}


void MenuItem::SetText(const string &text) {

    text_ = text;
}

void MenuItem::SetFunction(const std::function<void()> &function) {

    function_ = function;
}

string MenuItem::GetText() const {

    return text_;
}

std::function<void()> MenuItem::GetFunction() const {

    return function_;
}

void MenuItem::Run() {

    function_();
}
```

**Menu**

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_MENU_H
#define REGISTRY_MENU_H

#include "menuItem.h"
#include "showable.h"
#include <vector>

class Menu : Showable, Runnable {

public:

    Menu(std::initializer_list<MenuItem> menuItems);

    Menu(const std::vector<MenuItem> &menuItems);

    Menu();

    ~Menu() override;

    void SetRunning(bool running);

    void SetMenuItems(const std::vector<MenuItem> &menuItems);

    bool IsRunning() const;

    std::vector<MenuItem> GetMenuItems() const;

    std::string ToString() const;

    void Show() const override;

    void Run() override;

private:

    std::vector<MenuItem> menuItems_;
    bool running_;

    int GetInput();

    void Perform(int select);

    bool Quit();

};


#endif //REGISTRY_MENU_H
```

```
#include "../include/menu.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Menu::Menu(initializer_list<MenuItem> menuItems) : menuItems_(menuItems), running_(false) {

}

Menu::Menu(const vector<MenuItem> &menuItems) : menuItems_(menuItems) {

}

Menu::Menu() : running_(false), menuItems_() {

}


Menu::~Menu() {

};


void Menu::SetRunning(bool running) {

    running_ = running;
}


void Menu::SetMenuItems(const vector<MenuItem> &menuItems) {

    menuItems_ = menuItems;
}

bool Menu::IsRunning() const {

    return running_;
}

std::vector<MenuItem> Menu::GetMenuItems() const {

    return menuItems_;
}

string Menu::ToString() const {

    string items;

    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems_.size(); i++) {

        items += to_string(i) + " - " + menuItems_[i].GetText() + '\n';

    }

    return items;
}

void Menu::Show() const {

    cout << ToString();
}

int Menu::GetInput() {

    cout << "Choose a function: " << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";

    int select;
    cin >> select;
    while (cin.get() != '\n');

    while (select > menuItems_.size() - 1 || select < 0) {

        cout << "Incorrect function number!" << endl;
        cout << "Choose a function: " << endl;
        cout << "➡ ";
        cin >> select;
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
    }

    return select;
}


void Menu::Perform(int select) {

    menuItems_[select].Run();
}

bool Menu::Quit() {

    cout << "Do you want to continue working? 1 - yes, 0 - no" << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";

    int select;
    cin >> select;
    while (cin.get() != '\n');

    while (select < 0 || select > 1) {

        cout << "Incorrect data entry!" << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to continue working? 1 - yes, 0 - no" << endl;
        cout << "➡ ";
        cin >> select;
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
    }

    if (select == 0) {

        return false;

    } else {

        return true;
    }
}

void Menu::Run() {

    running_ = true;
    int select;

    do {

        Show();
        select = GetInput();
        Perform(select);
        running_ = Quit();

        if (!running_) {

            running_ = false;
            return;
        }


    } while (running_);
}
```

Hi all! I want to write a console menu, but I don’t know how to do it right, this is my version, please tell me what can be fixed or added. I'm not sure if it's normal that I have `cout` and `cin` in the menu logic.

In `Menu` I store a vector of `MenuItems`. `MenuItem` consists of a name and a polymorphic function wrapper `(std::function)`. `MenuItem` has a `Run()` method which will run the function.

`Menu` has a `Show()` method that will display the existing menu items.
In the `GetInput()` method of `Menu`, I get the function selection from the user and pass this selection to `Perform()`, where the corresponding `MenuItem` function will run.
The `Run()` method of `Menu` launches the menu, and in the loop, while the menu is running, I call `Show()`, `GetInput()`, and `Perform()` in turn.

Comment: You should explain better each section of code that you have. Also try to be more specific.

Comment: You should add more detail in each section so we can understand it better and give you a better solution.